# simple way for cross validation for any classifier

Tags: r, cross-validation

I am quite new to R.

I want to use a decision tree, c4.5, knn, logistic regression, svm and generalized linear models for classification on my data.

How can I use a cross validation method with fold value equal to 10 for training and testing?

Is there a function for all of mentioned classifiers?

Comment: Have you investigated the `train` function in the caret package?

Comment: @josilber Thanks,Which one of models in [modellist](http://topepo.github.io/caret/modelList.html) is desicion tree?